# Get Object not set to instance of an object when calling MSGraph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am busy debugging code on a application that is supposed to get Unread Mail with Attachments from a O365 box. I'm not very familiar with MSGraph, but I just want to get something out of the way before I spend to much time on it.

I have a ClientId, TenantId, ClientSecret and I use `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` like this

```
var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                  .Create(clientId)
                  .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                  .WithClientSecret(clientPassword)
                  .Build();
```

When I do

```
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
```

There are 0 accounts

I then call

```
var gsc = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(app, scopes);
```

to create `GraphServiceClient` and retrieves a token and add `requestMessage.Headers.Authorization` with the token. All of this works.

When I do any call however (`var user = await gsc.Me.Request().GetAsync();` or `var mail = await gsc.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().GetAsync();` I get an object not set to an instance of an object, and I'm not sure how exactly to find the cause of the problem.

The Api Permissions includes `Mail.Read` as one of the permissions. Is there something else I can look at that may cause the exception be thrown in Graph.dll

Stack trace

> at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.d__18.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__35.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__31``1.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Graph.MailFolderMessagesCollectionRequest.d__4.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

**UPDATE**
Playing with a new test app, I found that the error is caused by a `NoPermissionsInAccessToken` error from Graph. I tried TokenCredentials to see if I can find something that works. When I use the `ClientSecretCredential`, I get the same error. When I use the `UsernamePasswordCredential` it works, and I can retrieve mail for the user.

Currently in the portal the API permissions are setup for the application for `NoPermissionsInAccessToken' are` Mail.Read`and`User.Read`.
The user is setup in the Application with Default access Role and it was Directly Assigned. I'm not sure if the application needs more permissions for the application to read information.

Comment: Could you share the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: I've added the stack trave, but it does not say much :(

Comment: Are you able to provide the version of the SDK you are using? Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Core packages. Could you also share implementation of GetAuthenticatedGraphClient?

Comment: For my test I used the latest version (4.24, 2.0.7). I also managed to get some more out of the exception. It seems that I get a ` NoPermissionsInAccessToken` error back. I got this from my latest test app. I use the implementation as described in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/blob/master/1-Call-MSGraph/daemon-console/Program.cs. I am currently testing with that application, but am using .net framwork as our app is .net framework. What permissions needs to be set in Azure?

Comment: Ok, this is the latest. I am able to use the UserNamePasswordCredentials and that works, but when I use ClientSecretCredential, I get the `NoPermissionsInAccessToken`. I will update the question to give more information regarding the current permissions